# Place the asp:button to right inside <td></td>

Tags: html, asp.net

I want to align the button to the right part of td's, how can i achieve that using html coding ?

```
<td>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Text1">
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
<td align="right">
```

Comment: Hi Anik, i tried that but there is no "align" properties in asp:button , i am using VS 2005

Comment: got it, <td align="right"> works! :) Thanks .. so it is not working inside asp:button .. it will be on td instead.. thanks Anik :)